# Ebean postgresql (and playframework 2.1.1)

Tags: playframework, postgresql-9.2, ebean

I'm trying to create a simple table using ebean in playframework 2.1.1 with postgresql:

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "user")

public class User extends Model {

    @Id     
    public long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    public String email;
}
```

The `Ebean DDL` actually create the following:

```
create table user (

  id                        bigint not null,

  email             varchar(255),

  constraint pk_user primary key (id));

create sequence user_seq;
```

1. Why isn't `ebean` using `serial/bigserial`?
2. Is there a different way creating the table with `serial/bigserial` (I tried using other options that I checked and none of them worked)
3. If using a sequence (ex: user_seq) is the correct way (or rather the only way), why aren't them sequential - for example: inserted data and got id 300-350 and then 365 and then 366.. 
   No other user is connected, this behavior was repetitive (after few inserts).

thanks:)

Comment: If I could play devil's advocate for a second here I would pose: why does it matter?

Comment: 1. Want to know if it is a bug (or a feature :)

Comment: 2. I want to understand the mechanism of the sequence and why it doesn't act as expected (I don't see as good practice the id just jumping with no apparent reason).

Comment: It's the "normal" behaviour.  I would assume it's acting in that way to ensure atomicity of the value returned, it mentions in [the PostgreSQL docs -- in the Notes section](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html) that the values are assigned in cache blocks to 'sessions.'  I assume that these sessions are somehow linked to DB connections and the discontinuities map to requests over different connections.